# Portrait and Landscape ActionBar title size differ

Tags: android

Just create a simple empty Android project using the latest SDK (AndroidX)

The portrait mode, Android Title looks normal. However when turn to landscape, the Title font size shrink. (Note: the below image is in the same ratio, and notice the Title fond size differ.
[image]

Is this an Android Bug? What's the easiest way to workaround it?

Comment: Um, I'm pretty sure it's always been like that.

Comment: For example, [the portrait value](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml#58), and [the landscape value](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/res/res/values-land/dimens_material.xml#23), all the way back in Lollipop.

Comment: Looks explicitly coded this way. Any reason behind of doing so?

Comment: I'd imagine it's because there's less vertical space available in landscape, so they made the `ActionBar` in that mode a little thinner. That's speculation, though, and would fall under "primarily opinion-based", if it's your actual question, now.

Comment: Thanks. I think it's a bug in Android. So my question is what would be the easiest way to fix and get the font back to its original font size regardless of orientation?

Comment: I have filed an issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140952845

Comment: It's not a bug. It's always been that way. If you want the same size in both modes, then set your own values in your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Set the style for Title in style.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Set textsize as you like. in example it is 20sp

```
<style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
```